# Autenticação JWT TOKEN não esta persistindo

Tags: react-native, autenticação, axios, jwt

Bom, toda vez que faço reload na minha aplicação ou abro e fecho ela, tenho que colocar o login e senha, pode ser algum erro no meu código, alguém poderia dar uma olhada? Pois preciso quando abrir fazer reload não precisar colocar a senha e o email.

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://10.0.3.2:3333/',
});

api.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@App:token');

    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});

export default api;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cássio, esse componente seu aí me parece certo. A questão é como você está fazendo essa checagem no componente de entrada. Como se fosse assim:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hasChecked: false,
    hasUser: false
  };

  async componentDidMout() {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SeuUsuario');
    this.setState({
      hasChecked: true,
      hasUser: !!user,
    })
  }
  // Aqui no render a gente vê se foi checado. Se sim você repassa pra suas rotas que
  // está logado ou não e exibe o login ou a home do seu projeto
  render() {
    if (!this.state.hasChecked) return null;

    return(
      <Routes hasUser ={this.state.hasUser} />
    );
  }
}
```

Na no seu componente de rotas você verifica se o hasUser veio **TRUE** se sim, mostra a Home, se não mostra o Login.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Dev, isso me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar esse código de exemplo

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { create } from "apisauce";
import { Constants } from "../constants";
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native'
const api = create({
  baseURL: Constants.API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 3000
});

api.addAsyncRequestTransform(request => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@omnix:token");

  if (token) {
    request.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
});

api.addResponseTransform(response => {
  if (!response.ok) throw response;
});

export default api;
```

Só uma observação, o AsyncStore vai ser removido do core do React Native, atualize para o repositório do react-native-community

Comment: O AsyncStore vai ser removido do react-native? Daqui pra frente vai ter que usar então as bibliotecas?

Comment: Sim, será substituido pelo repositorio no https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage